# How to print/display a specific element of a set in GAMS?

Tags: software, gams

I have the follwoing set in GAMS
set i /10,13,15/;

how can I display the second element of this set ?

Comment: If this set is used in a decision variable, and also if in the optimal solution, this variable has a value you have to see this value in the `display` part. Otherwise, you may have an issue on the model side. Do you check this?

Comment: Also, if you need to keep a specific element of a set, the following does what you want: (Set i  /10, 15, 13 /;
Parameter report(i,*);
report(i,'value')$(ord(i)=2) = i.val ;
display report;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a subset:

```
set 
   i /10,13,15/
   isub(i)
;
isub(i) = ord(i)=2;
display isub;
```

This gives:

```
----      6 SET isub  

13
```

This only works for ordered sets.